# What is the best programming practice to simulate an evolved class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have two classes:

```
class SwordsMan{
  /*...*/
  virtual SwordsMan* evolve()
};

class Warrior: public SwordsMan{
  /*...*/
};
```

What I am trying to aim for is that the SwordsMan evolves into a Warrior once he has enough experience. What would be the best practice to do for implementing this evolve() function given that I want to delete the "this" SwordsMan object once he evolves?

Comment: that completely depends on how you want a `Swordsman` evolve into a `Warrior`. Btw I would think twice, if inheritance is the right way to go. Maybe `Warrior` is just a title that a `Swordsman` can have

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I was thinking that because a warrior has additional abilities and properties that a normal SwordsMan doesn't have , (including the swordsman abilities), then inheritance would be the way to go. Also, why the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a better idea to separate the objects' implementation from the management of their lifetime.

```
class SwordsMan {
  virtual std::unique_ptr<SwordsMan> evolve();
};

class Warrior: public SwordsMan { };
```

In the class one layer above, the code could look like this:

```
auto swordsMan = std::make_unique<SwordsMan>(); // Get a swordsman

if(auto evolved = swordsMan->evolve()) // Ask him to evolve
    swordsMan = std::move(evolved); // Replace him
```

If you only call `evolve()` when you definitely want to upgrade the swordsman, you can drop the `if`:

```
swordsMan = swordsMan->evolve();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Do you agree that this is an acceptable usage of inheritance? Given the fact  that a Warrior has all the abilities and properties of a SwordsMan and additional ones that a Swordsman doesn't have?

Comment: @user3508551 sounds fine to me :)